# How do I close the gap at the top of the page where my banner is?

Tags: html, css

I need my banner to sit tight against the top of the browser. Problem is that there is a small white gap btween the div that the image sits in and the top...Ive tried setting padding to 0 for div and body and it doesnt work :-(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Shared/Css/Style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Shared/Css/Navigation.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="../../Shared/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="padding-top:0px;">


        <div id="header-image">
            <img alt="Header" src="../../Security/FileFetcher.aspx?RelativePathToFile=App/images/topnav.jpg&mimetype=image/jpeg" />
        </div>



    </div>
</body>
</html>


body 
{
    background: url("/Security/FileFetcher.aspx?RelativePathToFile=App/images/background.jpg&mimetype=image/jpeg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#main-content-container
{
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:930px; 
    border-left:2px solid Gray; 
    border-right:2px solid Gray;
}


#header-image 
{
    width:960px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: probably its a part of the background image. Did you check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `<body>`'s margin:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this above the body options in your stylesheet

```
 * {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

You could also look at one of the many [CSS reset options](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20reset)